# How to use Curl with API Key and API Secret to check license key

Tags: php, api, curl

i want to check the License key with Curl and API Key and API Secret

this is Return Value

Upon successful processing, License Manager will return a plain text

message that will have two or three lines similar to the following:

Success License key WPLICMxx4bc2xxx1e471
or
Error Secret key is invalid

Sample PHP Code 
  Below is a sample PHP code that shows how you can create a license via 
    the API

```
/*** Mandatory data ***/ 
// Post URL 
$postURL = ""; 
// The Secret key 
$secretKey = "597c038865e788.30430360"; 

/*** Optional Data ***/ 
$firstname = "John"; 
$lastname = "Doe"; 
$email = "john.doe@gmail.com"; 

// prepare the data 
$data = array (); 
$data['secret_key'] = $secretKey; 
$data['slm_action'] = 'slm_create_new'; 
$data['first_name'] = $firstname; 
$data['last_name'] = $lastname; 
$data['email'] = $email; 

// send data to post URL 
$ch = curl_init ($postURL); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$returnValue = curl_exec ($ch); 

// Process the return values 
//var_dump($returnValue);
```

i want to check the License key with Curl and API Key and API Secret

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please explain. This is a decent question?

Comment: i want to check the License key with Curl and API Key and API Secret

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the HTTPHEADER, using defined key(s), so something like

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'user: UserName',
  'pass: blahPasswordHere'
));`

`user` and `pass` will need to be changed to whatever the receiving server is looking for

Comment: I'm not here to do your job for you. If you don't know, it's your role as a developer to learn your craft. CURL is not difficult.